# RDS Licensing Manager: LS Upgraded Reactivation needed, how to resolve?

Tags: remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2022

Who can help me setting out the required steps for solving this situation?
[image: LS Upgraded Reactivation needed]

I think this causing this`Remote Desktop License Issue`:

[image: Remote Desktop License Issue]

When looking into the details, it looks like that the License needs to be transferred from Windows Server 2019 to Windows Server 2022 (I upgraded the server in November 2023)

[image: LS Upgraded Reactivation needed]

Comment: CALs don't "transfer". They are per edition. You need to contact your reseller. IF you want to continue using per device licenses. Per user is not enforced.

Comment: it seems user didn't research before post question

Comment: Dear @VaibhavPanmand, I actually feel a bit offended by your remark. Our company has only one Windows server and very little in-house knowledge to maintain it. Most of the software we use is open source (little license issue there). I did try to research the error. The problem seems that there are way too many answers, and none of these answered my specific question since most of them are about how to install a license.  Something that may seem obvious to you might not be evident to others.

Comment: This resource has helped me in the end: https://community.spiceworks.com/t/server-2019-with-50-rds-user-cals-what-happens-when-i-upgrade-to-server-2022/932434